# An arithmetic hierarchy without bounded quantifiers

Tags: nt.number-theory, lo.logic

I posted this question on math.stackexchange.com with no answers (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4337852/an-arithmetic-hierarchy-without-bounded-quantifiers).

Let $\exists_n$ formulas in the language of arithmetic be defined like $\Sigma_n$ formulas, except that bounded quantifiers count toward the number of quantifier alternations. For example, $\exists_1$ formulas are purely existential formulas, those of the form $\exists \bar{y} \phi(\bar{x}, \bar{y})$, where $\phi$ is quantifier-free. For all $n \ge 1$, are all $\Sigma_n$ formulas equivalent to $\exists_n$ formulas, in the sense that if $\phi$ is $\Sigma_n$, then there is a $\exists_n$ formula $\psi$ such that $\mathbb{N} \models \forall \bar{x} (\phi(\bar{x}) \leftrightarrow \psi(\bar{x}))$? I'm also curious whether we can even have $\mathrm{PA} \vdash \forall \bar{x} (\phi(\bar{x}) \leftrightarrow \psi(\bar{x}))$, where $\mathrm{PA}$ is Peano arithmetic.

It's easy to see that the answer is negative for $n = 0$, and for $n=1$ the answer is affirmative by the MRDP theorem.

Comment: Every $\Sigma_n$ or $\Pi_n$ formula is equivalent over PA to $n$ alternating quantifiers followed by a bounded formula. Don't you get a positive answer to your question for $n \geq 1$ by using the MRDP theorem to replace the innermost $\Sigma_1$ or $\Pi_1$ formula with an $\exists_1$ or $\forall_1$ formula?

Comment: One subtlety in @GabeGoldberg's comment is that you need the "internal" MRDP theorem rather than the MRDP theorem as usually stated - that is, you need to check that the proof of MRDP goes through in PA. But it does, so that's fine.

Comment: @GabeGoldberg Thanks. I forgot bounded quantifiers can be pushed after the unbounded quantifiers.